# How do I extract data from a main table based on this specific scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014`. I have a table (T1) which contains the list of IDs of cancelled bookings and their equivalent re-bookings.

Extract of table `T1`:

```
CancelledID       Re-bookingID
  301                754
  387                801
  400                900
  ...
```

Each CancelledID has a unique equivalent in the Re-bookingID column.

I have another table (`T2`) which contains the list of ALL BookingIDs with additional information related to each ID. An extract of this table is shown below:

```
BookingID     MonthOfStay      RoomNights
...
301             2019-03-01        10
387             2019-04-01         7
400             2019-03-01         5
754             2019-08-01        10
801             2019-09-01         3
900             2019-07-01         5
900             2019-08-01         4
...
```

I need a  t-sql query which will me the following output:

```
  BookingID       Cancelled_MonthOfStay     Re-booking_MonthOfStay     RoomNights
    301                2019-03-01                                           10
    387                2019-04-01                                            7
    400                2019-03-01                                            5
    754                                           2019-08-01                10
    801                                           2019-09-01                 3
    900                                           2019-07-01                 5
    900                                           2019-08-01                 4
```

As you can see, a re-booking can span over 2 months with additional room nights.

I am thinking about "Joins" between the 2 tables but I am stuck at the logic to be used for the "Joins" (if that is the right way of tackling the problem).

*Note: The end in mind is to use this data to build a matrix with Cancelled_MonthOfStay as rows and Re-booking_MonthOfStay as columns. The value inside this matrix will be the total RoomNights.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I wish I could show something. I am really stuck with the Join problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the easiest method would be to unpivot your data in the "`Cancellations`" table, and then use a `CASE` expression to display the data in the appropriate column:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Cancellations (CancelledID int, RebookingID int)
INSERT INTO dbo.Cancellations
VALUES (301,754),
       (387,801),
       (400,900);

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Bookings (BookingID int, MonthOfStay date, RoomNights int)
INSERT INTO dbo.Bookings
VALUES (301,'20190301',10),
       (387,'20190401', 7),
       (400,'20190301', 5),
       (754,'20190801',10),
       (801,'20190901', 3),
       (900,'20190701', 5),
       (900,'20190801', 4);
GO

SELECT B.BookingID,
       CASE V.BookingType WHEN 'Cancellation' THEN B.MonthOfStay END AS CancelledMonthOfStay,
       CASE V.BookingType WHEN 'Rebooking' THEN B.MonthOfStay END AS RebookedMonthOfStay,
       B.RoomNights
FROM dbo.Cancellations C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(C.CancelledID, 'Cancellation'),(C.RebookingID, 'Rebooking')) V(BookingID,BookingType)
     JOIN dbo.Bookings B ON V.BookingID = B.BookingID
ORDER BY B.BookingID;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Cancellations;
DROP TABLE dbo.Bookings;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can LEFT JOIN the T1 table twice to your T2 table. And then use CASE to leave the right columns empty.

```
SELECT T2.bookingID,
    case when canc.CancelledID is not null then t2.monthOfSTay end as cancelled_MonthOfStay,
    case when reb.rebookingID is not null then t2.monthOfStay end as rebooking_MonthOfStay

FROM T2
LEFT JOIN T1 as canc
    on T2.bookingID = canc.CancelledID
LEFT JOIN T1 as reb
    on T2.bookingID = reb.rebookingID
```